# Failed when binding the blox,neo-6m driver to uart 1 on BeagleBoneBlack-wireless

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, buildroot

i'm trying to bind the gnss driver ubx neo6m to my sensor mapped on uart1

Source of the driver kernel 5.10.23 : : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.23/source/drivers/gnss

Source of the DTS i'm using : : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.23/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack-wireless.dts

i patched the device tree adding :

```
uart1_pins: pinmux_uart1_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = < 0x180 0x30 0x00 0x184 0x00 0x00 >;
    };
```

and

```
&uart1 {
 status="okay";
 pinctrl-names = "default";
 pinctrl-0 = <&uart1_pins>;
 gps@0{
    compatible = "blox,neo-6m";
    vcc-supply = <0>;
    current-speed = <115200>;
    };
};
```

but after booting i don't see any gnss device under /dev

Thanks

Comment: Did you rebuild and install the updated modules & dtb files?

Comment: yes -- resolved -> compatible field was wrong : need to be u-blox,neo-6m